# Good textbooks on probability and/or stochastic processes, emphasizing simulation

Tags: pr.probability, mathematics-education, books

Any recommendations for textbooks on probability and/or stochastic processes that emphasize simulation? I'll be teaching this course in the Fall.

Comment: The new book Markov Chains and Mixing Times by Levin, Peres, and Wilmer (http://www.oberlin.edu/markov/) looks quite nice. It doesn't emphasize code, but it does cover aspects of simulation. You might also consider Bremaud: http://books.google.com/books?id=IHn7Lx15ifUC

Comment: Also for continuous-time stochastic processes you might consider Gardiner: http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Stochastic-Methods-Chemistry-Synergetics/dp/3540616349